# XCTest calls 2 different implementations(module and after mock) with failing

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I want to test `controller` with `presenter`, passing mock loader to `presenter`.
I have `compose` method which has `StoreType` argument for presenter. I use production controller with presenter, just mocking store. Even without `compose` method, with direct building in `makeSUT`, I have problem, that I run test of `viewDidLoad` and: 1. created VC with production `store` in `SceneDelegate`, `viewDidLoad` is called, after that test fails, 2. created VC with `MockStore` and it doesn't matter already.

```
func testViewDidLoad() {
            let store = MockStore()
    let sut = makeSUT(localStore: store)
   
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.history.isEmpty) // just example
}

func makeSUT(localStore: StoreType) -> MyViewController {
   return Composer.compose(localStore: localStore)
}

final class Composer {
    static func compose(localStore: StoreType) -> MyViewController {
        let loader = LocalLoader(store: localStore)
        let presenter = MyPresenter(localLoader: loader)
        let vc = MyViewController(presenter: presenter)
        presenter.view = vc
        return vc
    }
}
```

The same `compose` method is called in `SceneDelegate` in `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session`.

I don't understand why I have two calls of `viewDidLoad`, initialization with production implementation on test? How can I remove it, what's wrong here?

Comment: Insufficient information — too many unknowns in your code.

Comment: if I run test and make breakpoint or print in ```compose``` method and will check the type of ```localStore``` I see first time ```ProdStore``` and then ```MockStore```. Test will show that I have result of ```ProdStore```, instead of ```MockStore```

Comment: Is this the first view controller your app presents when it runs?